# ffmpeg extract alpha channel from prores

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract alpha channel from ProRes (mov) in greyscale to a separate mp4 file (to emulate video with transperancy on the html page later).

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -hide_banner -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vf alphaextract,format=yuv420p out.mp4
```

but I don't get a filled alpha channel but only a sort of border of it. Pretty sure that original file is ok (tried with different files) and encoding it to webm showed correct transperency.

What I get from ffmpeg
[image]

How original file looks like
[image]

Comment: The original file is either the color channel matte or a composited view. You shouldn't expect that when extracting alpha, regardless of whether ffmpeg produces an unexpected result with your command. Can you share the input?

Comment: if I encode original prores file to vp9 (webm) in lossless mode and then extract alpha, then it works as expected so I guess it's ffmpeg issue.
Original video was found in google discussion. The link is https://08488297638989341201.googlegroups.com/attach/85d30cd6b8095/Circle%20Ink%20Bleed_10.mov?part=0.1&vt=ANaJVrGMDN-p3hoCfl4Xjh9-4E_-YRKlpyG7GXHqCwogXnfUYKiUvmW1CwUSvy5jwn8XzPSD_JbtBZrTYMrGi_XZyo9_oXraabu_xsUKsmP0w7Q-grRSWO8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug; patched in git master.

Workaround for older versions is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf format=yuva444p16le,alphaextract,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```